# How to determine which bounding boxes are immediately to the right or below a given bounding box?

Tags: ocr, azure-cognitive-services

I'm using Azure cognitive services to perform some OCR on this image:
[Machine faceplate image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CtXD.jpg)
I put the bounding box information into a pandas dataset:
[pandas dataframe of bounding box info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioWjJ.png)

Edit: put in image descriptions.

What I want to do is be able to get the bounding box immediately to the right of and below a bounding box that has a label, for instance, SERIAL NUMBER, because the value associated with the label should be in one of those two places.  I'm not sure exactly how to go about this.

I have calculated the midpoint of each bounding box as I wanted to use those to determine the closest bounding box, but I don't know how to determine whether or not the box is to the right or below the bounding box with the label.

Comment: A couple of scenarios that would be good to add clarity on here:

1. Do you want both the bounding box directly to the right and below, or the closet bounding box that is either right or below (left or right)?
2. Or do you want the bounding box that is to the right first?
3. Or do you want two bounding boxes; the one to the right (if there is one at the same level) and the one directly below?
4. Or do you want to be able to get the bounding boxes in left-to-right reading order?

Comment: Ideally, I want things in left-to-right reading order.  If the image is rotated, would it still be possible to get the boxes in left-to-right order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the below code I was able to do the task for the provided data
Please check the comments for more details.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

results = {}

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    label = row['text']

    # Initialize variables to store the minimum distances and the indices of the closest bounding boxes
    min_right_distance = float('inf')
    closest_right_bbox_index = -1
    min_below_distance = float('inf')
    closest_below_bbox_index = -1

    # Get the midpoint of the current label bounding box
    label_mid_x = (row['top_left_x'] + row['bottom_left_x']) / 2
    label_mid_y = (row['top_left_y'] + row['bottom_left_y']) / 2

    # Iterate through the DataFrame to find the closest right and below bounding boxes for the current label
    for idx, other_row in df.iterrows():
        if idx != index:
            # Calculate the distance between midpoints
            distance = np.sqrt((other_row['top_left_x'] - label_mid_x)**2 + (other_row['top_left_y'] - label_mid_y)**2)

            # Check if the bounding box is to the right or below the label bounding box
            is_right = other_row['top_left_x'] > row['bottom_right_x'] and other_row['top_left_y'] < row['bottom_right_y']
            is_below = other_row['top_left_y'] > row['bottom_left_y']

            # Update the minimum distances and the indices of the closest bounding boxes if the conditions are satisfied
            if is_right and distance < min_right_distance:
                min_right_distance = distance
                closest_right_bbox_index = idx
            if is_below and distance < min_below_distance and not is_right:
                min_below_distance = distance
                closest_below_bbox_index = idx

    # Get the closest right and below bounding boxes
    closest_right_bbox = df.loc[closest_right_bbox_index] if closest_right_bbox_index >= 0 else None
    closest_below_bbox = df.loc[closest_below_bbox_index] if closest_below_bbox_index >= 0 else None

    # Add the results to the dictionary
    results[label] = {"Closest Right Bounding Box": closest_right_bbox, "Closest Below Bounding Box": closest_below_bbox}

# Print the results
for label, result in results.items():
    print("Label:", label)

    closest_right_bbox = result["Closest Right Bounding Box"]
    closest_below_bbox = result["Closest Below Bounding Box"]

    if closest_right_bbox is not None:
        print("Closest Right Bounding Box:")
        print(closest_right_bbox["text"])
    else:
        print("No closest right bounding box found.")
    
    if closest_below_bbox is not None:
        print("Closest Below Bounding Box:")
        print(closest_below_bbox["text"])
    else:
        print("No closest below bounding box found.")
    
    print()
```

[image]

The code the getting result based on the distance and location of the box.
**Sample Output:**

```
Label: SERIAL NUMBER
Closest Right Bounding Box:
MODEL NUMBER
Closest Below Bounding Box:
FB00991100197

Label: MODEL NUMBER
No closest right bounding box found.
Closest Below Bounding Box:
CAH004FDAC

Label: FB00991100197
Closest Right Bounding Box:
MODEL NUMBER
Closest Below Bounding Box:
This

Label: CAH004FDAC
No closest right bounding box found.
Closest Below Bounding Box:
the

Label: This
Closest Right Bounding Box:
unit is sold
Closest Below Bounding Box:
limited

Label: unit is sold
Closest Right Bounding Box:
subject
Closest Below Bounding Box:
warranty.
```

**Note**: The code provides a initial approach to do the task, please modify the code as per your need.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  I shall modify it as needed as it occurs to me that if the image is rotated, the value could be to the left of or above its label.

Answer (score 0):

Had to make this an answer as I couldn't put the image in a comment. Note that the order of the bounding boxes already appear to be in reading order, left-to-right. As such you would simply go to the next value in the index to get the next set of text in the reading order. Here is your original image with bounding boxes on it to show this.

[image]

That said, this may be the case if the document is somewhat upright. If the image is rotated more, the bounding box of the text may not match that reading order or of the text but be in reading order of the boxes themselves. As a test, try rotating the image more and passing it into the service (best to try the service you are using as different OCR tech may handle this differently).

Comment: I know that some of the images will be rotated.  It doesn't matter to the OCR portion, but I figure the bounding boxes will also be rotated.